# 'stack smashing detected abc2 terminated Aborted' shows when looping an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, ubuntu-14.04

When I try to compile the below code terminal says `stack smashing detected abc2 terminated Aborted (core dumped)`. This error shows when for loop going through the **two dimensional array**.

What I want to do is get user input to first column using `cin>>arr[0][i];` and 0 for every other columns using`arr[i+1][r]=0;`.

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void displayArray(int arr[][4],int row,int col);
    int main(){
    int arr[3][4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            cout<<"enter value ";
            cin>>arr[0][i];
            for(int r=0;r<3;r++){
                    arr[i+1][r]=0;
            }
    }



            displayArray(arr,3,4);

            return 0;
    }

    void displayArray(int arr[][4],int row,int col){
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                    for(int r=0;r<col;r++){
                            cout<<arr[i][r]<<" ";
                    }cout<<endl;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Please reformat the code. You could also add some more information. When does the stack smashing happen?

Comment: arr[i+1][r]=0; the "+1" does not make so much sense to me.

Comment: @Marco does it make sense right now.

Comment: @exilit Reformated. Is it understandable now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going beyond the bounds of your array here:

```
int arr[3][4];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
 //...
   arr[i+1][r]=0; // <-- i+1 when i == 2 is going to give trouble
//...
}
```

If `i >= 2`, you're writing to `arr[3]`, `arr[4]`, etc.  This is a memory overwrite and the behavior then becomes undefined.

Obviously the fix is either to throttle the loop back so that `i` is always less than 2, or your array's first dimension needs to be increased from 2 to a bigger number.